# i want the program to say if the item that the user input is not on the list of sandwhich orders to say we do not have it stock

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#deli # no pasreami 
sandwich_orders = ['veggie','pastrami', 'grilled cheese','pastrami', 'turkey','pastrami', 'roast beef']
finished_sandwiches = []
prompt = "\nwhat kind of sandwich would you like?"
prompt += "\nEnter 'done' when finished."
print("Sorry we are out of pastrami today ")
while 'pastrami' in sandwich_orders:
    sandwich_orders.remove('pastrami')
print("\n but we have these type of sandwiches today on the list :  ")
for sand in sandwich_orders:
    print(sand)
while True:
     food = input(prompt)
 if food == 'done':
    print("You order " + str(finished_sandwiches) + "sandwiches")
    break
 else:
    finished_sandwiches.append(food)
    print("adding " + food)
```

trying to get it where the user enters pastrami that is says we are not in stock please order another type of sandwich and also to add sandwiches that are only in the list and Can you nest a if statement in a else block.FYI the code i have presented is only to finish problem 7-8 and 7-9 in python crash course.

Comment: What is wrong with your current code?

Comment: trying to get it where the user enters pastrami that is says we are not in stock please order another type of sandwich and also to add sandwiches that are only in the list and Can you nest a if statement in a else block.FYI the code i have presented is only to finish problem 7-8 and 7-9 in python crash course.

Comment: Include that in the question itself, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the sandwich the user entered is in the sandwich_orders list. If it is then add it to finished sandwiches if not give the error and loop again.

```py
# deli # no pasreami
sandwich_orders = ['veggie', 'pastrami', 'grilled cheese', 'pastrami', 'turkey', 'pastrami', 'roast beef']
finished_sandwiches = []

print("Sorry we are out of pastrami today ")
while 'pastrami' in sandwich_orders:
    sandwich_orders.remove('pastrami')

while True:
    print("Please choose from the following sandwich choices:")
    print(*["\t" + sandwich for sandwich in sandwich_orders], sep="\n")
    food = input("Sandwich choice (or done to exit): ")
    if food == 'done':
        print("You order " + str(finished_sandwiches) + "sandwiches")
        break
    else:
        if food in sandwich_orders:
            finished_sandwiches.append(food)
            print("adding " + food)
        else:
            print("We do not have that in stock, please choose an item fro the sandwich list")
```

Answer (score 0):

I see there are `3` pastrami sandwiches in the menu. And **yes** we can nest a if statement in a else block.

```py
sandwich_orders = ['veggie','pastrami', 'grilled cheese','pastrami', 'turkey','pastrami', 'roast beef']
finished_sandwiches = []

print("\nWe have these sandwiches today on the menu: \n")
for sand in sandwich_orders:
    print(sand)

prompt = "\nWhat kind of sandwich would you like?"
prompt += "\nEnter 'done' when finished.\n"
print(prompt)
while True:
    food = input()
    if food == 'done':
        print("\nYou order of sandwiche(s):")
        for food in finished_sandwiches:
            print(food)
        break
    else:
        if food not in sandwich_orders:
            print('{} sandwich out of stock. Please order another type of sandwich'.format(food))
        else:
            sandwich_orders.remove(food)
            finished_sandwiches.append(food)
            print("added " + food)
```

**Output:**

[image: output]